# Issues with metaprop function for computing pooled specificity in meta-analysis

Tags: r, confidence-interval, meta-analysis, diagnostic, sensitivity-specificity

I am training to learn how to perform meta-analysis using R. I conducted a meta-analysis using the `metaprop` function in R with the provided dataset. The goal is to compute the pooled specificity using the code snippet below:

```
Data <- structure(
  list(
    detection = c(
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Lateral flow",
      "Lateral flow",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence",
      "Fluorescence"
    ),
    TP = c(91, 139,
           29, 59, 32, 32, 24, 18, 80, 77, 261, 51),
    TN = c(62, 53, 20,
           20, 40, 37, 22, 26, 40, 19, 127, 27),
    FP = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2,
           3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0),
    FN = c(25, 1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 1, 2, 27, 0, 7,
           12)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

I encounter multiple problems when I wanted to use `metaprop` to compute pooled specificity using this code:

```
library(meta)
metaprop(event = TN,
         n = TN + FP,
         studlab = rownames(Data2),
         data = Data,
         sm = "PLOGIT",
         method.ci = "CP",
         subgroup = Data$detection,
         comb.fixed=FALSE,
         comb.random=TRUE,
         title = "Specificity")
```

This is the result:

```
Review:     Specificity

Number of studies: k = 12
Number of observations: o = 506
Number of events: e = 493

                     proportion           95%-CI
Random effects model     0.9829 [0.9462; 0.9947]

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.7642; tau = 0.8742; I^2 = 0.0% [0.0%; 58.3%]; H = 1.00 [1.00; 1.55]

Test of heterogeneity:
          Q d.f. p-value
 Wald  3.80   11  0.9755
 LRT  19.52   11  0.0523

Results for subgroups (random effects model):
                                           k proportion           95%-CI  tau^2    tau    Q  I^2
detection = Fluorescence                  10     0.9761 [0.9374; 0.9911] 0.3949 0.6284 3.80 0.0%
detection = Lateral flow   2     1.0000 [0.0000; 1.0000]      0      0 0.00 0.0%

Test for subgroup differences (random effects model):
                  Q d.f. p-value
Between groups 0.00    1  0.9995

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Random intercept logistic regression model
- Maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Logit transformation
- Continuity correction of 0.5 in studies with zero cell frequencies
  (only used to calculate individual study results)
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
3: In vcov.merMod(res.ML) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
4: Ratio of largest to smallest sampling variance extremely large. May not be able to obtain stable results. 
5: Ratio of largest to smallest sampling variance extremely large. May not be able to obtain stable results.
```

I have some questions:

**Confidence Interval for Lateral Flow:**
The confidence interval for specificity in the "Lateral flow" subgroup is reported as [0.0000; 1.0000]. Given the absence of false positives in both studies using the "lateral flow" method, I expected a more precise interval. Why does it return (0-1)?

**Interpretation of Warnings:**
The function generates several warning messages, and I'm unclear about their implications.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect. Can you say why you think that you should have got a narrower confidence interval?

Comment: I thought 95% between 0 and 1 is just meaningless. Every specificity value in any test should lie somewhere within 0 and 1! I think there is a problem in the model fitting because there are a couple of warnings, but I don't know what they mean even though I searched a lot.

Comment: Most of the statistics you want to calculate don't make a lot of sense on a group with only 2 studies.

Comment: @wzbillings I know two studies are not enough, but I have another dataset with similar groups but the dataset has false positives in all studies and I did not encounter with any errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you are using an inappropriate model for the meta-analysis of diagnostic studies. Although the sensitivity and specificity are independent within study they are not necessarily so between studies (because of threshold effects). You need to use a proper bivariate model. Since you use R trying the mada package may be a good start.

See [the article by Gatsonis and Paliwal](https://www.ajronline.org/doi/10.2214/AJR.06.0226) for why your analysis is "not methodologically defensible"

Comment: Thank you very much. I was actually using [this tutorial article](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/cclm-2022-1256/html#j_cclm-2022-1256_fig_002) and I've seen other articles using the same methodology as the one I've mentioned. For the univariate analysis they used `meta` and later further into analysis they will use `mada` for other types of analysis. But I am stuck in the first step!